# HTTPS request connection timeout (NGINX)

Tags: https, security-certificate, nginx, centos

I tried a lot by reading different answers on Stackoverflow and other forums but unable to identify the error, can someone please check the below configuration and tell me what could be wrong?

```
server {
    server_name test.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://176.X.XX.XXX:30805;
    }
}

server {
    server_name test.domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_access_test main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_error_test info;

    ssl_certificate /root/ssl/wildcard.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/wildcard.domain.com.pem;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        proxy_pass http://176.X.XX.XXX:30805;
    }
}
```

I am able to access the page on `http://test.example.com` but not able to get it on `https://test.example.com` (instead a connection timeout), I also tried to redirect from port 80 to 443 but it didn't help because I tried a lot of different combinations of configurations

Comment: Sounds like you haven't opened port 443, Apache and Nginx have no control over the internal firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved after installing `firewall-cmd` and adding a rule for port 443.